# Count all embeded link in any Page

Tags: php, jquery

```
public function actionPagelink(){
 if(isset($_POST['link']))
    $allLink=($_POST['link']);
    $linkcount['inbound']=0;
    $linkcount['outbound']=0;
    foreach ($allLink as $singlelink)
        {
           if (strpos(Yii::$app->params["siteUrl"], $singlelink)) {
               $linkcount['inbound']++;
            }else 
             $linkcount['outbound']++;
        } //( $data['inbound']);die();
    // $_POST['daterange']
    return json_encode($linkcount);

}
```

***jQuery code:-***

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var href = []; 
    a.find('a').each(function() { 
        href.push($(this).attr('href')); 
    }); loadlink(href); 
}); 
function loadlink(link){ 
    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'page/pagelink', 
        type: 'post', 
        data: {link:link}, 
        success: function (data) { 
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); 
            $('div.pageanalysisform').find('h2#inbound').text('InBoundLink:'+obj.inbound); $('div.pageanalysisform').find('h2#outbound').text('OutBoundLink:'+obj.outbound); 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

I have done this to count inbound and outbound link.But, I have no idea to count ***embedded link***.Any help would be great.

Comment: define `embeded link`

Comment: What should that contain? Can you describe how to get all embedded links?

Comment: I get link now I have to differentiate embeded link.

Comment: I solved it thanks